# Type error: cannot read property getid of null in google script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, html, javascript

When I run this script it show me this error. I can't understand what I do. Its function is to transfer results from html form to Google Sheet. Can anyone solve this problem?

```
var sheetName = 'Sheet1'
        var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()

        function intialSetup () {
          var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
          scriptProp.setProperty('key', activeSpreadsheet.getId())
        }

        function doPost (e) {
          var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
          lock.tryLock(10000)

          try {
            var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
            var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(sheetName)

            //var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
            var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues().map(function(row){
            return row[0];
            });
            var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

            var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
              return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
            })

            sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

            return ContentService
              .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
              .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
          }

          catch (e) {
            return ContentService
              .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
              .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
          }

          finally {
            lock.releaseLock()
          }
        }
```

[image: chek this image]

Answer (score 0):

`SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` is returning `null`. This happens when the script project is not bounded to a spreadsheet and when the bounded project is opened by using it's URL or from the Google Apps Script hub (https://script.google.com) instead of opening from the container.

There are two possible solutions,

1. use your script in bounded project
2. replace `getActiveSpreadsheet()` by `open(file)`, `openById(id)` or `openByUrl(url)` (you should have to pass an appropriate object / value

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#open(File)
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String)
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openByUrl(String)